# skimage regionprops orientation producing confusing results

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I am trying to understand the orientation output from `skimage.measure.regionprops_table` but I am a bit confused. Can anyone help me a bit in understanding the output of the orientation?

According to documentation, *`orientation` returns angle between the 0th axis (rows) and the major axis of the ellipse that has the same second moments as the region, ranging from -pi/2 to pi/2 counter-clockwise.*

In the below code example, I created a rectangle along the x-axis so the major axis is along the x-axis. I was hoping to get 0 degree orientation angle but I get 90 degrees. For a 90 degree rotated rectangle, it returns 0 degree orientation angle. I am bit confused why is this the case. Shouldn't it be the other way around? For a rectangle placed at 30 degrees, orientation returns -60 degrees.

What do they mean with the 0th axis (rows)? May be someone can guide me according to the below example.

Here is a simple code that I tried:

```
from skimage.transform import rotate
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import measure
import pandas as pd
import math
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

testimg = np.zeros([100,150],dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(testimg, (30, 40), (70, 50), (255,0,0), -1)
#testimg = img_as_ubyte(rotate(testimg, angle=90, order=0))
ret1, thresh = cv2.threshold(testimg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')

ret3, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh)
plt.imshow(markers)
testprops = measure.regionprops_table(markers, properties=['label', 'area', 'centroid', 'major_axis_length', 'minor_axis_length', 'orientation']) # v18.x
testdata = pd.DataFrame(testprops)
testdata['angle_degree'] = math.degrees(testdata['orientation'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scikit-image, in 2D, the "0th" axis is the rows, which go from 0 at the top left corner to n at the bottom left corner. You can read more about this in the "coordinate conventions" page of the documentation:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.19.x/user_guide/numpy_images.html#coordinate-conventions

This is done to match the coordinates with the indexing of NumPy arrays. This means that indeed, orientation of 0 corresponds to the vertical, and 90 to the horizontal.